# Randomize rows when google doc is opened

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a petition with a google form and doc. I've found an app script that will take the responses from the form and input them into a table on the doc. To help reduce the bias early respondents may face, I am trying to develop a script that will randomize the rows of the table every time the document is opened. Trying to scramble the signatures so that the same signatures aren't always at the top (can't be targeted).

Can anyone help me with this?

Below is the code I am using to populate the table from the form

```
 
  //Since there could be a bunch of people submitting, we lock the script with each execution
  //with a 30 second timeout so nothing gets overwritten
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
 
  //Here we read the variables from the form submission event
  const date = new Date(e.values[0]).toLocaleDateString();
  //of you can use toLocaleString method if you want the time in the doc
  const name = e.values[1];
  const employeeNumber = e.values[2];
   
  var form = FormApp.openById('');
 
  const num = form.getResponses().length;
  var num1 = num.toString()
 
  //Next format those values as an array that corresponds to the table row layout
  //in your Google Doc
  const tableCells = [num1,name,employeeNumber]
 
  //Next we open the letter and get its body
  const letter = DocumentApp.openById('')
  const body = letter.getBody();
 
  //Next we get the first table in the doc and append an empty table row
  const table = body.getTables()[0]
  const tableRow = table.appendTableRow()
 
  //Here we loop through our table cells from above and add
  // a table cell to the table row for each piece of data
  tableCells.forEach(function(cell, index){
    let appendedCell = tableRow.appendTableCell(cell)
  })
 
 
 
  //here we save and close our letter and then release a lock
  letter.saveAndClose(); 
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Got this from a helpful vimeo tutorial by Abhishek Narula and Rebekah Modrak.

Answer (score 0):

#### Randomize row in a google document table

First function Creates a table in a google document from a table in a spreadsheet

```
function creatTable() {
  const style1 = {};
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]=DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const tA = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.clear();
  let n = body.getNumChildren();
  for(let i =0;i<n-1;i++) {
    if(i==0) {
      body.getChild(i).asText().setText('');
    } else {
      body.getChild(i).removeFromParent()
    }    
  }
  let table=body.appendTable(tA).setAttributes(style1);
}
```

Second function reads the table from the document and randomizes the rows it and reloads the table.  This function actually searches through all of the children to find a table. If there is more than one table it will randomize all of them  so it will need to be modified to integrate with your specific document.

This now removes the first line and then randomizes the array and then adds the first line back

```
function readandrandomizetable() {
  const style1 = {};
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let vs = [];
  let fl = '';
  [...Array.from(new Array(body.getNumChildren()).keys())].forEach(idx => {
    let ch = body.getChild(idx);
    if (ch.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      Logger.log(`This is the index I want: ${idx}`);
      let tbl = ch.asTable();
      [...Array.from(new Array(tbl.getNumRows()).keys())].forEach(ridx => {
        let s = tbl.getRow(ridx).getText().split('\n');
        //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(s));
        vs.push(s);
      });
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
      fl = vs.shift();
      vs.sort((a, b) => {
        vA = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        vB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        return vA - vB;
      });
      vs.unshift(fl);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  body.clear();
  let n = body.getNumChildren();
  for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      body.getChild(i).asText().setText('');
    } else {
      body.getChild(i).removeFromParent()
    }
  }
  body.appendTable(vs).setAttributes(style1);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Cooper! I have the first function working already (but thank you for the time and effort). The second function almost does exactly what I was hoping for (in fact it looks like it almost does it a little too well haha). Is there a way to freeze the top row (column titles) and then just randomize the names/signatures below? 

It also appears to delete the main body of the letter that is not in a table and just replaces the whole document with the table? Or maybe I just didn't implement it correctly?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's now just randomizing the 2 and following lines.  I believe it also will not mess with the other children in the document now.

Comment: Ok thanks! Ya it's randomizing properly now but it's still clearing everything out of the document besides the table. 

Again, really appreciate this help. Do you have a tip jar or anything like that?

Comment: Then please tell me what the child index is for the table

Comment: Apologies but I'm even worse than a beginner when it comes to this stuff. Where do I locate this information for you?

Comment: Just use the new code I just edited and the index will appear after the phrase "This is the index I want:"

Comment: I've edited the initial post to show the code I am using to populate the table from the form. "This is the index I want: 24"